# Android immersive mode, the bars appears when swipe top or bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-immersive

My app android need to be full screen (immersive mode).
API LEVEL: 19

With the following code it works, but when I swipe on top o on bottom, the bars temporarily appears.

How can I prevent the user from accessing the bars?

```
    //onCreate
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //FULLSCREEN - ma con swipe top - bottom appaiono
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    );
```

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1):

```
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

try this one